# Python3: What is the proper format for compounding continue statements. x and (y or z)

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

My program reads file names and categorizes their line count based on the file name. I am currently trying to error proof my code to report any regular appearing files that aren't .txt or .xlsx. The reason I am asking and not just finishing with an else statement is because it will regularly have to sift though .zip, .csv, .xls that will need a similar statement. I found this question for another language but I don't understand how to translate it to python.

What I am trying to make python understand:

> True if:
>   x is necessary AND (either y OR z)

so it needs two things but the second thing is flexible

```
if os.path.isfile(fname) and file.endswith != ".txt" or file.endswith != ".xlsx":
  cant_read += 1
```

My attempt at the logic is:

```
x = 2
z = 2
y = 3
w = 2

if x == z and (x == (y or w)):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

> This code logic gives me False as is and True if y and w are swapped. y = 2 and w = 3

Right now I've only been using this for an error counter, but I will need it for the other extensions soon.

Thanks, if anyone can explain the format to me it's been on my "to figure out" list for awhile.

Comment: Just compound them, you almost had it: `if os.path.isfile(fname) and (file.endswith != ".txt" or file.endswith != ".xlsx"): ...`, and for multiple checks for equality you can use: `if x == z and x in (y, w): ...`

Comment: `if x == z and (x == (y or w))` will only be true if `x == True` and `z == True`, or `x == False` and `z == False`, but **nothing else**, because `(y or w)` returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: Is this gonna help: `file.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.any_extension'))` as you can use a tuple to store all the potential extensions you want to prune?

Comment: Thanks @Chen Chen, I'll try that out. Thanks zwer that works better, but I'll have to read about the in statements more